# How does the win/loss streak scale?

Tags: dota-autochess

It doesn't seem to be linear.

I think after 2 wins/losses in a row you get +1G, then a little later it scales to 3, and I think I've seen with a very long streak a +5.

So how does it scale? Is it the same for losses and wins?